# I want to remove the trailing slash from the redirection URL

Tags: jquery, redirect

I have a code with the url redirection, it has url parameters.
I want the url to not contain trailing slash(/) in the end before the url parameters start.
if is run :  `goalnugget.com/store_redirection.html?src=external-blog`
Firefox is forcefully adding training slash on redirection url before url parameters. How can it be removed?

Tried it to redirect using the below code, But once it redirects it has a slash before ?(question mark automatically)
`window.location= ("https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/goal-nugget?src=external-blog");`

```
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
if(isFirefox){
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location= ("https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/goal-nugget?src=blog");
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: It's not Firefox causing the trailing slash, as it happens in all other browsers too. It is caused by the rewrite rules on the website itself. As such there is absolutely nothing you can do to prevent it

Comment: Why would this slash be a problem in the first place?